# Как сделать функцию, которая вызывает саму себя через определенное количество времени? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Какой-нибудь простейший пример: каждую секунду переменная `i` увеличивается на единицу. Изначально `i = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let i = 0;

function increaseCounter() {
    ++i;
}


setInterval(() => {
    increaseCounter();
    console.log(i);
}, 1000)
```

---

Функция, которая вызывает саму себя через определенное количество времени:

```js
let i = 0;

async function increaseCounter() {
  console.log(i);
  i++;
    
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  increaseCounter();
}

increaseCounter();
```

Comment: разве функция вызывает тут саму себя?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я смотрел в тело вопроса)) но в принципе написал второй вариант, который является примером на вопрос из заголовка

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вам подойдет **setInterval** - подробнее тут [setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval)

```js
let i = 0;

function ourFunction() {
    i++;
}


setInterval(() => {
    ourFunction();
}, 1000)
```